# C# open source or free financial time-series analysis programs/libraries

Tags: c#, time-series, quantitative-finance

I'm particularly looking for something implementing Vector AutoRegression (VAR) model, which is available in R (vars package). I believe IMSL Numerical Libraries can do this but it's not free ..  Thanks for the help!